# How to add Account (child) to Entity (parent) object

Tags: lookup, object

We have Entity object, which is the collection of all the Account. Now I want to change the Account And put it to another Entity object but I am getting some Error:

> Apex trigger onAccount caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: onAccount: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 1 with id 006b000000IQw2uAAD; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Please check that Subscription Package, Effective Date, Contract Term and Billing Agreement are properly filled.: []: ()

Please help me find out why I cant add and how could I add this one Account to that Entity object. With Data loader I could try it?
Thanks and regards

Comment: The error says that there is a validation on the fields as mentioned and the record expects those fields to be filled. It seems you don't have those values populated thus causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Under Setup > Object Manager > Click on the Account object, and on the left look 'Validation Rules' , click on it and go through each of the rules. You will be then able to identify why your trigger failed.

Comment: We are having only one Validation rule and that also is Managed.

Comment: Did you try what Jayant Das' suggestion based on the error ? i.e 'Please check that Subscription Package, Effective Date, Contract Term and Billing Agreement are properly filled.'  when you update the Account ensure these fields are populated.